# How to compute gradient on AWS neuron inferentia

Tags: amazon-ec2, pytorch, bert-language-model

I have to compute gradient on BERT model on inferentia. For this I guess I also need access to the hidden layers. Im currently not able to proceed because of not finding literature on the net for inferentia. There seems to be some non inferentia links but those do not work for this case.

Amongst the things which are missing are how to get positional embeddings.

Pl let me know in case you know of code which does this.

I am also exploring captum for this but so far no luck.

Thanks in advance Ajay